# Run SSIS Package skipping Invalid dates

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've a DWH Table which has Date Value stored as int.Now I wanna get all records for a day which are active on a day with conditions as start_date<=@date and End_Date>@DATE
for almost close to 2 years.

I've used a for loop and 3 variables where in hardcoded FROM_DATE and TO_DATE as 20130101 and 20150107 and the 3 variable VAR_DATE initially set TO_DATE and decreasing by 1 until it reaches FROM_DATE.

But after reaching 20150101...It's starting to insert values for 20150100,20150099 and so on..

Is there a way where in I can check to see if the VAR_DATE column being used is actually a valid date(by convert and comparing on the go) or any possible way of using a result set..

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: The code sees integer 20150101, not the date '20150101' so why shouldn't it go to 20150100? If you want to store dates as integers, you should consider using a Calendar table where actual dates are mapped to integers, and use those mapped values instead.

Comment: How about convert VAR_DATE to a date, subtract one day and then convert it back to an integer again?

Answer (score 0):

Use a script to convert the integer into a string. Then parse it into a date object like so:

```
DateTime parsedDate;
bool parseResult = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate)
```

Then parseResult will be true if it's a valid date.